# How to promote app in Google play app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-ads-api

Recently I've developed a app and published it in the google play. Now it's been few weeks but I'm not getting enough downloads. Now I've decided to promote app in Google play search. For ex: when user search something related to my app then my app should show up first. Just like in below image. Can somebody guide how to do this promotion. Please note that I wanted to promote only in google play search. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your Google Play Developer Console, you can create an *AdWords* campaign to promote your app through ads on Google Play, Google Search along with sites and apps that are part of the Google Display Network.

Note:
If you are are creating an *AdWords* campaign for the first time on the Developer Console, the account owner needs to set up the first campaign. Once the account owner runs an AdWords campaign on the Developer Console, other account users with 'Create  AdWords campaigns' permissions can create campaigns.

For more information regarding Adwords, you may view the link below: https://developers.google.com/adwords/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google ad words for this work. You can refer to the following [page](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2549053https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2549053?hl=en) . Start a campaign as instructed.

Comment: the link you have provided is broken, I've tried creating capaign in google ad words, but i wanted to show my app only in google play search list. and i would like to pay per impression rather than paying per install or something. Please guide me if you have some info as i'm new to this google adword thing.,

Answer (score 1):

When you searching effective ways to promote your app you need to think about target audience of your app and you will find good ways. Of course as for every developer eternity option is not so attractive.

When you just published you app you can use several ways to get more installs:

- Ask your friends to try it and write review (also you can use forums
  for this);
- Create Facebook/Twitter/etc page for it;
- Ask websites which publish reviews on new apps to review yours;
- Use special services to boost your ranking in Google Play to make your app visible for oganic users (like [CPIMobi](https://cpimobi.com/?a=149) or Whitemobi);
- Test it for bugs and always update with better version.

The process will be faster if you are ready to work on marketing strategies and spend some time and budget to promote it.

Hope this helps